# Undefined response when using nuxt-link routing

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am getting data for my Nuxt application using the Axios asyncData function and whenever I navigate through the pages using nuxt-links I get an error 'slug undefined'. If i then reload the page it works fine and loads the data. Any ideas?

_vue.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
     <div :v-if="post[0].slug">{{ post[0].slug }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios' 

export default {

  components: {
  },

  asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    return axios.get(`https://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=${params.vue}`)
    .then((res) => {
      return { post: res.data }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

header component referenced in the layout

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li><nuxt-link to="/category1">Test 1</nuxt-link></li>
 <li><nuxt-link to="/category2">Test 2</nuxt-link></li>
 <li><nuxt-link to="/category3">Test 3</nuxt-link></li>
 <li><nuxt-link to="/category4">Test 4</nuxt-link></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your error dont come from the code you posted. U dont reference anywhere slug in the code you posted and the error about it

Comment: @Aldarund - thanks I have changed my post so its a bit easier to understand. Have added the reference too.

Comment: there must be some errors in console. I bet it would be cors error